# Проблемы с ресемплингом аудио данных

Tags: c++, c, ffmpeg

Столкнулся с проблемой аудио-ресемплинга, точнее не совсем понятной логикой работы функци swr_convert_frame.

Исходные данные такие:
Входной пакет (AVFrame):

```
SampleRate = 8000
SampleFormat = AV_SAMPLE_FMT_S16
ChannelLayout = MONO
```

Параметры выходного пакета установлены такие же. То есть объект SwrContext
инициализирован на конвертацию в такие же параметры.

Это сделано для проверки общности работы алгоритма ресемплинга (тест).

Так вот, при таких настройках я ожидал "прозрачной" работы данной функции, между тем функция возвращает AVERROR_INPUT_CHANGED.

> Input changed between calls. Reconfiguration is required.
>   (перевод) Входные данные изменились между вызовами, требуется реконфигурация.

В целом, я никак не изменяю входные данные. То есть вышеуказанные параметры в AVFrame не меняются.

О какой реконфигурации идет речь?

Есть ли какие-нибудь особенности ресемплинга в ffmpeg?

Comment: Возможно вы не в том порядке вызываете функции, или пропустили где-то какой-то init.

Comment: @nick_n_a копаюсь в доке, а там как обычно старое использование с новым перемешано и, похоже вы правы, я не в том порядке что-то инициализирую. Разбираюсь, короче )